# What (and how) to control for in adjusted wage-gap regressions?

Tags: labor-economics, regression, wages, empirical-methods, discrimination

**Background**: The unconditional wage gap between some group and the rest is often estimated using a regression of the form
$$ 
w_{it} = \alpha + g_{it}'\theta +\epsilon_{it}
$$
where $w_{it}$ is log of real wage, $g_{it}$ the binary group indicator, and $\epsilon_{it}$ an iid error term. If omitted productivity variables are correlated with $g_{it}$, then $\theta$ might instead serve as a proxy for these omitted variables.

The adjusted wage gap is usually estimated by including a set of control $X$ capturing productivity differences between individuals. It seems to me there is no consensus on what variables should be included in $X$ and how these should be included. I have seen hugely different specifications and little discussion on what is correct. Two things are particularly confusing to me

**Questions**

1. Is there an argument to be made to include only few, exogenous controls to avoid the issue of [bad controls](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r493.pdf) in $X$? In particular, I would worry that some controls like occupation or industry are examples of 'colliders'

[image]

2. I have seen versions where $X$ is just included as additional controls
   $$ 
   w_{it} = \alpha + g_{it}'\theta + X'\beta + \epsilon_{it}
   $$
   and I have seen versions using saturated models with interactions of the group variable with the additional controls
   $$ 
   w_{it} = \alpha + g_{it}'\theta + X'\beta + \sum \gamma_j x_{it}'g_{it}' + \epsilon_{it}
   $$
   I think the first version is closer to what I would think of adjusted wage gap. Indeed, I am not sure how I would interpret $\theta$ in the saturated model?